# How to join two tables and rename the new table?

Tags: sql-server-2008, visual-studio-2019

I want to join two tables in sql and want to connect it with my .net project where I used web forms. help is needed. thank you

Answer (score 1):

Normally this is done by creating a view

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-view-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

Answer (score 0):

Joining tables is done using "join" syntax in your query.

Try reading the [Microsoft Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/performance/joins?view=sql-server-ver15) on the subject.